# How can search results be cached?

Tags: search, caching, elasticsearch, lucene

How do I implement caching mechanism of search results as on stackoverflow?
How does elastic search and lucene deal with caching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now, you can cache in two different ways within Elasticsearch

1. [Filter cache](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/filter-caching.html) - Here if you can offload as many constraints which don't take part in scoring of results,  you can have segment level caches for that particular filter alone. This along with [warmer API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-warmers.html) provides some decent amount in memory based caching for the filters applied alone
2. [Shard request cache *](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html) - You can cache the results ( Other than hits) on query level. This is pretty new feature and should provide a good amount of caching. But still _source needs to be still taken the shards.

Within Elasticsearch you can exploit these features to attain a good amount of caching.
Also, you can explore other caching option external to Elasticsearch to memcache or other in memory caches.

- previously called [shared query cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/shard-query-cache.html)

Comment: A correction to your answer - Currently Shard Query Cache *does not* cache hits. It only caches hit count, aggregations and suggestions and that too when `search_type` is set to `count`

Comment: @bsarkar - Thanks for your input. I knew it didn't cache _source , but not hits. Correction made in the answer

Answer (score 3):

Warmers

Warmers have been removed. There have been significant improvements to the index that make warmers not necessary anymore.

in ElasticSearch 5.4+